# cdsapi era5 download to computer

Tags: python, era5

I have some data I'd like to download from the era5 model via the cdsapi package:

```
import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

url = c.retrieve(
    'reanalysis-era5-single-levels',
    {
        'product_type': 'reanalysis',
        'format': 'grib',
        'variable': 'total_precipitation',
        'year': '2021',
        'month': '01',
        'day': '01',
        'time': '00:00',
    },
    'download.grib')
```

Has this downloaded the the grib file to my computer or has it been created and saved to CDS's site?

If I print `url`:

```
Result(content_length=2076600,content_type=application/x-grib,location=https://download-0004.copernicus-climate.eu/cache-compute-0004/cache/data2/adaptor.mars.internal-1612475135.0349507-29868-7-7ed52a50-6bc6-493b-8b3e-92ac91518fd0.grib)
```

If it's just been saved to that online location is there any way to skip that step and download the data direclty to the computer in that same `c.retrieve` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been downloaded to your computer, probably to same folder where you run your srript from.

You can also specify different location if you put custom full path instead of `'download.grib'`.
File can also be found on cds portal in [your requests](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/yourrequests) section